# Magento 2 - Redirect to home page when error on login post

Tags: magento2, login

I create a login popup template, **only extending the phtml file** and moving the xml block in my popup panel. It works fine, but when the user make some error (e.g. wrong the password) I want to redirect on the home page and open the panel with the error message.

I don't know how to do this, because by default magento redirect the user on customer login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I wrote my controller that extend `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` this is my controller:

```
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost {
/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Session $customerSession
 * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
 * @param CustomerUrl $customerHelperData
 * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
 * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
    CustomerUrl $customerHelperData,
    Validator $formKeyValidator,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
) {
    parent::__construct($context,
        $customerSession,
        $customerAccountManagement,
        $customerHelperData,
        $formKeyValidator,
        $accountRedirect);
}

/**
 * Login post action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $baseUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $refererUrl = explode('?', $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl())[0];
    $previusPageNoError = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $refererUrl);
    $previusPage = $previusPageNoError . '?error=1';

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $this->session->regenerateId();
                if (isset($login['productId'])){
                    $this->addItemToWishlist($login['productId'], $this->session->getCustomer()->getId());
                    $wishListIndex = 'wishlist';
                }
            } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                $message = __(
                    'This account is not confirmed.' .
                    ' <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                    $value
                );
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                return $this->_redirect($previusPage);
            } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                return $this->_redirect($previusPage);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Invalid login or password.'));
                return $this->_redirect($previusPage);
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            return $this->_redirect($previusPage);
        }
    }

    if ($previusPageNoError === 'checkout/') {
        return $this->_redirect($previusPageNoError);
    } elseif (isset($wishListIndex)) {
        return $this->_redirect($wishListIndex);
    } else {
        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
    }
}

private function addItemToWishlist($idProduct, $customerId)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $wishlist = $objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
    $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
    $wishlist->addNewItem($idProduct);
    $wishlist->save();
}}
```

Now in my phtml I only need to check with jquery if the url path contain `?error=1` and open the popup.

This is my phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($) {

    function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[0] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[0];
            }
        }
    }

    if (getUrlParameter('error') == 'error') {
       // open your login popup 
    }

});</script>
```